# Best init script for running an application as a separate user

Tags: perl, initialization, debian, plack

I have an application that runs in a user account (Plack-based) and want an init script.

It seems as easy as "sudo $user start_server ...". I just wrote an LSB script using start-stop-daemon and it is really clumsy and verbose. It doesn't feel like the right way.

After scouring for a bit and looking at a log of examples, I'm still not sure what the best way to do this is and there isn't a cohesive guide that I've found.

Right now I have it working with:

```
start-stop-daemon --background --quiet --start --pidfile $PIDFILE \
                --make-pidfile --chuid $DAEMONUSER \
                --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
```

With DAEMON and DAEMON_OPTS as:

```
DAEMON="/home/mediamogul/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current/bin/start_server"
DAEMON_OPTS="--port $PORT -- starman --workers $WORKERS /home/mediamogul/MediaMogul/script/mediamogul.psgi"
```

This then requires me to adjust how to detect running, because it's a perl script so perl is showing up as the command and not "start_server".

(I'm running this out of a perlbrew on that user account so it is completely separate from the system perl, that's why the paths are pointing to a perl in the user dir)

Is this really the best way to go about doing this? It seems very clunky to me, but I'm not an admin type.

Comment: If it's useful I can post my full init script to gist.

Comment: I'm interested in an anwser too. I'm quite surprised that start_server doesn't daemonize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--pid` option to starman to have it write the PID when the app starts, if you use the same filename as you give start-stop-daemon then it will work nicly.

For example, from one of my init.d scripts:

```
SITENAME=mysite
PORT=5000
DIR=/websites/mysite
SCRIPT=bin/app.pl
USER=davidp
```

PIDFILE=/var/run/site-$SITENAME.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
    start-stop-daemon --start --chuid $USER --chdir $DIR  \
        --pidfile=$PIDFILE \
        --exec /usr/local/bin/starman -- -p $PORT $SCRIPT -D --pid $PIDFILE
    ;;
  stop)
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

It's very close to what you are already doing, and I'll admit it is a little clumsy, granted, but it works - having Starman write the PID file means that start-stop-daemon can reliably start & stop it.

Comment: This answer is incomplete: it bypasses the usage of the [start_server superdaemon](https://metacpan.org/module/KAZUHO/Server-Starter-0.12/start_server) from the question.